# Batch Loop %Variable% times

Tags: android, shell, batch-file

I'm creating a batch file so I can easily control my phone using ADB

I have done most of it, however I want to be capable of controlling my volume level.

I know that `adb shell input keyevent 25` decreases by 1 level, however is there a way of using variables to do it x amount of times?

So, I currently have:

```
cd C:\platform-tools-latest-windows\platform-tools
cls
title DECREASING Volume
cls
echo Decreasing Volume...
adb shell input keyevent 25
pause
cls
goto :USERAREA
```

If I were to ask the user for how many levels to decrease by, I would start with:

```
cd C:\platform-tools-latest-windows\platform-tools
cls
title DECREASE Volume
cls
set /p VOL=How many levels should it decrease by: 
pause
echo Decreasing Volume...
adb shell input keyevent 25
pause
cls
goto :USERAREA
```

However, I don't know how to repeat the command `adb shell input keyevent 25` 
 `%VOL%` number of times.

Please help me with this,

Thank You

yg.swagness

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for /L %%a in (1,1,%vol%) do adb shell input keyevent 25
```

see `for /?` from the prompt for documentation

Comment: Thanks very much @Magoo , I have upvoted and accepted your answer